# Adding a character to a Label after a forever-repeating cycle in a function tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter, tcl

In tkinter, I have been trying to add a way to add checkmarks to a label every time a looping countdown finishes. I've been thinking about using `Label.config(text="...")` but I couldn't figure out how that would work. Then I tried doing `Label = Label + "..."` but it gave me an `AttributeError` because I couldn't contactanate a Label with a string.

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

my_label = Label()

def something():
    ...
    ...
    ...
    my_label = my_label + "✔"

something()
my_label.pack()
```

On first function call I expected a Tk window with a checkmark at the top.
But instead I got:

```py
AttrubuteError: cannot contactenate 'Label' with 'str'
```

Any help is appreciated: Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tk.Label is a widget, not simply a string.  You should be able to use:

`my_label['text'] += '...'`

Answer (score 1):

With .config you can configure the label attributes

```
my_label.config(text = f"{my_text}✔")
```